# How to create an Excel Shape (Polyline)?

Tags: excel, vb.net

I want to draw a polygon in Excel from VB.NET. whenever I use the `AddPolyline` method it gives the following error:

> 'The specified parameter has an incorrect data type.'

**My code is:**

```
Dim X1 As New Point
Dim X2 As New Point (25, 100)
Dim X3 As New Point (100, 50)
Dim X4 As New Point (150, 50)
Dim X5 As New Point (25, 100)

Dim arrPoint() As Point = {X1, X2, X3, X4, X5}
Dim rc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Shape = objSheet.Shapes.AddPolyline(arrPoint)
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Please format your code so that it is readable.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-addpolyline-method-excel - the method appears to expect an array of numbers, not an array of `Point` objects. So, as the message clearly states, you're giving it the wrong type of data. There's some example code shown of the kind of data you can provide.  Did you look at the documentation at all when you were investigating your error?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>VBA</strike> Excel Object Library (Interop.Excel) doesn't have a `Point` class/structure out of the box. You need to use a two-dimensional array of Singles rather than an array of Points. This should work.

```
Dim arr As Single(,) = {{25, 100}, {100, 50}, {150, 50}, {25, 100}}
Dim rc As Excel.Shape = objSheet.Shapes.AddPolyline(arr)
```

---

If you have an array/list of Points already (received from somewhere) and you'd like to use it, you can write a helper function to convert it to a 2D array. It would look something like this:

```
Private Function PointsTo2DArray(points As IList(Of Point)) As Single(,)
    Dim arr(points.Count - 1, 1) As Single
    For i = 0 To points.Count - 1
        arr(i, 0) = points(i).X
        arr(i, 1) = points(i).Y
    Next

    Return arr
End Function
```

Then you can easily do the following:

```
Dim X1 As New Point(25, 100)
Dim X2 As New Point(100, 50)
Dim X3 As New Point(150, 50)
Dim X4 As New Point(25, 100)

' Assuming you already have this array.
' If you Then don't, don't create one and use a 2D array directly as shown above.
Dim arrPoint() As Point = {X1, X2, X3, X4}

Dim rc As Excel.Shape = xlSheet.Shapes.AddPolyline(PointsTo2DArray(arrPoint))
```

**The result in both cases:**

[image: Polyline]

### References:

[`Shapes.AddPolyline` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-addpolyline-method-excel).

Comment: Problem is I am writing code in vb.net not VBA. And in vb.net it gives same error for array of singles or points  - 'The specified parameter has an incorrect data type.'

Comment: I know you're using VB.NET, but all the methods, variables, etc. you use to access Excel objects are part of the COM wrapper (which is not a managed .NET code). You cannot pass a Point to the `AddPolyline` method for two reasons: 1) The .NET Point structure isn't recognized by the Excel Interop object library. 2) Even if it is, the method expects a 2D array anyway, therefore, you can't pass a Point instead.